# Passing a value to a child component Angular2

Tags: angular, web-component

I'm trying to pass a value from a parent component to a child component I tried this:

This is my parent component:

```
import {Component, View, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';

import {DisplayCard} from '../display-card/display-card';

@Component({
  selector: 'display'
})
@View({
  templateUrl: './components/display/display.html',
  directives: [DisplayCard, NgFor]
})
export class Display {
  displays: Array<any>;

  constructor(){
    this.displays = [
      {name: "Lobby", appName: "Animal App", Source: 3},
      {name: "Wall", appName: "Idk App", Source: 3},
      {name: "Other Wall", appName: "Monkey App", Source: 3},
      {name: "Lobby Kiosk", appName: "Car App", Source: 3},
      {name: "Another Brick in the Wall", appName: "Pink Floyd App", Source: 3},
    ]
  }
}
```

Parent component HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-3" *ng-for="#display of displays">
    <display-card name="{{display.name}}"></display-card>
</div>
```

Child component:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'display-card'
})

@View({
  templateUrl: './components/display-card/display-card.html'
})

export class DisplayCard{
  name: string;
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<div class="display-card">
    <div class="display-card-header">

    </div>
  <div class="display-card-body">
    <h1 class="display-card-title">{{name}}</h1>
    <h4 class="display-card-subtitle"></h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

I added the `name` property to the child component since this is the error I'm getting when I try this out:

```
EXCEPTION: Can't bind to 'name' since it isn't a known property of the '<display-card>' element and there are no matching directives with a corresponding property
```

Is this even possible with components?

Comment: PS :- `@view` has been droped in angular2 beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the `properties` on your Component declaration :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'display-card',
  properties: ['name']
})
```

Comment: **properties** have been renamed to **inputs** in the alpha38